# Linq to Entities question

Tags: c#, linq, frameworks, entity

Is there a (fairly) simple explanation of why I can't do this:

```
var EmpList = from emp in context.Employees
              orderby emp.LastName
              select new { Name = emp.FirstName + " " + emp.LastName };
```

And further, is it possible to achieve this in the query or do I have to do this kind of processing after, with a foreach or something similar?

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* do that.

However it seems unnecessary to create an anonymous type with only one member. Try this instead:

```
var employeeNames =
    from emp in context.Employees
    orderby emp.LastName
    select emp.FirstName + " " + emp.LastName;
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use IQueryable:)?

Comment: No - I changed it to `var` now. But sometimes it is useful to know what the type is. Especially if you want to return it as a method result.

Comment: That is not what I meant, but it doesn't matter any more:)

Comment: @Shawn:  I'm not at the computer atm so I can't say exactly what the error was, I'll post later if unresolved   @Mark: thanks, I'll check it out later; I just simplified for example but I was sure it was getting hung up on that.. perhaps my error is elsewhere

Comment: Thanks all. You were, of course, correct.  I examined my code and realized my mistake was occurring when I was accessing the members of the anonymous type, not in the query.  Thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you *can* do that. You can also do this:

```
var EmpList = from emp in context.Employees
              let name = emp.FirstName + " " + emp.LastName
              orderby emp.LastName
              select name;
```

Haven't tested this in Studio though.